# point cloud to low polly mesh

Tags: algorithm, mesh, triangulation, smoothing, point-clouds

I am using the Kinect sensor to generate a point cloud of a person.
I need to generate from the point cloud the corresponding set of collision surfaces in NVidia PhysX.
To achieve it i have to smooth and after triangulate it to concave mesh/set of convex meshes.
I've found only 1 smoothing algorithm:

```
    The Moving Least Squares.
```

To triangulate i've found few algorithms:

```
    Greedy Projection Triangulation or
    Constrained Delaunay triangulation.
    Ear clipping algorithm
```

And [ready solution](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/Surface_reconstruction_points_3/Chapter_main.html) witch needs an oriented points as input data.
I also want to do it in realtime(at initialization create mesh and after move parts of it corresponding to real person moves) so i need fast methods.
 Also smoothing algorithm must return < 1000 points to achieve low polly meshes. 
Can u advise some useful methods?

Comment: I'm not familiar with NVidia PhysX... You really need the 3D mesh or just the contour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use The Point Cloud Library (PCL).

You can find functions for downsampling in module [Filters](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/group__filters.html).
And for meshing in the module [Surface](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/group__surface.html).

So you should be able to create low poly meshes from your point clouds in realtime.